# NodeJS to RabbitMQ: TypeError: Cannot read property 'createChannel' of undefined

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I keep encountering this error. My RabbitMQ works fine with my Python script but doesn't work with my NodeJS script. Here's the code snippet for reference:

```
const CONN_URL = 'amqp://<username>:<password>@<ip_address>:<port>/<queue_name>';
var amqp  = require('amqplib/callback_api');
amqp.connect(CONN_URL, function (err, conn) {
   conn.createChannel(function (err, channel) {
      ch = channel;
   });
});
```

My connection from the client server to the RabbitMQ server is fine (tested thru Telnet) but it seems to not work with my NodeJS script. I tried googling but no solutions came up.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is in your CONN_URL. Try without specifying the queue_name or make sure that the username, password and IP address it's correct.

Comment: @Subburaj the error is mentioned in the title.

Comment: @Subburaj   conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
       ^

Comment: @Ronald Do `amqp.connect(CONN_URL, function (err, conn) { console.log(err)` and see whether some err is throwing, my guess is that it throwing some error, that's y ur conn is undefined

Comment: @Subburaj Error: Socket closed abruptly during opening handshake. very weird. this doesn't happen with my python script

Comment: Its straightforward it throws some error, resolve the error automatically it will work

Comment: Is there an error in the server logs?